# Product of random variables: is this product distribution correct?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

It is known that the distribution function of a product of two random variables $Z = XY$ with $X \sim f_X$ and $Y \sim f_Y$ is

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(\frac{z}{x})\frac{1}{|x|}dx
$$

This assumes that both $X$ and $Y$ can take values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Say Y is a standard uniform distribution (constant density equal to $1$ over $[0; 1]$), then the integral can be shown to become

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{z}^\infty f_X(x)\frac{1}{|x|}dx
$$

Essentially, because the support for $f_Y$ is compact, the PDF is non-zero only for values of $\frac{z}{x} \in [0; 1] \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq \frac{z}{x} \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{z}$. This can be interpreted as $z \leq x \leq +\infty$, if I am correct.

My question is, would it be possible to come up with an arbitrary distribution for $Y$ with compact support and at the same time get rid of the $\frac{1}{| x |}$ term? I was thinking in the line of

$$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b}|y|, & \text{if} -b \leq y \leq b \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

And set $b = 1$ so that the PDF of $Z$ becomes

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-z}^{z} f_X(x)dx
$$

But could this be called a PDF?

Comment: Since the integral of a probability density over $\mathbb R$ is equal to one, it is clear that $\lim_{z\to\infty} f_Z(z) = 1$. Since $f_Z\geqslant 0$, it would thus integrate to $+\infty$. So I don't believe such a distribution can exist.

Comment: This also assumes $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Math1000 the calculation arrives to a somewhat convenient form, which can be evaluated. Does this show that although the calculation can be convenient, the result can sometimes be impossible?